# How to extract certain data while filtering out the ones including colspan?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For example:

```
<tbody>
<tr><td colspan="2"><p>Unwanted Text 1</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://www.example.com">Text 1</a></td>
<td>Nonesense 1</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://www.example2.com">Text 2</a></td>
<td>Nonesense2</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><p class="second-title">Unwanted Text 1</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried:

```
soup.select('tr')
for x in g:
    print(x.contents[0].text)
```

Output:

```
Unwanted Text 1
Text 1
Text 2
Unwanted Text 2
```

How can I only get "Text 1" and "Text 2" while omitting the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the `a` elements directly:

```
for item in soup.select('tr > td > a'):
    print(item.get_text())
```

Or, if you specifically want to skip rows with `td` elements having `colspan` attributes:

```
for item in soup.select('tr'):
    if item.find("td", colspan=True):
        continue
    print(item.td.get_text())  # get text of the first cell in the row
```

Comment: Awesome, the second answer is the one I was looking for. Thanks.